# After weird malfunction, toilet bowl won't fill unless I hold flusher

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Yesterday my toilet did something weird--after a normal flush it did not refill all the way (fills a couple of inches only,) the water took on a slightly dark/grey tint (still clear) and there was black dirt/grit settled in the bottom of the bowl.  I flushed a few times to see what would happen.  Gradually the darkness and dirt cleared, but the issue remained, the toilet flushed without a problem but the bowl would only fill a few inches.

Strangely, the tank's filling and emptying appears normal when compared to my other toilet, and we can get the bowl to fill by holding the flusher down after a flush.  It fills to slightly more than normal then drains to normal.  But then on the next flush, if the flusher is not held, the bowl does not fill again.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: By the flusher, do you mean the handle outside of the tank, or the sealing flap at the bottom of the tank?  It sounds like the flusher flap is not sealing the tank, so it does not fill.  If so replace the flap and clean around the hole.

Comment: A picture of the tank with the lid off might help here. But most toilet flush mechanisms are fairly similar.

Comment: I wonder if some kind of dirt/contamination got into the water supply line, and is now clogging some valve in the tank.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about the grit (bits of decomposed/shattered tube?), but it sounds like the small tube that should be directing a stream of water into the overflow standpipe to refill the bowl is not pointing into the overflow standpipe anymore.